# Take value of hidden field in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml, hidden-field, togglebutton

I am new on Rails. I have a hidden field and a toggle button in haml. How can i take the value of the hidden field and if is 0 then i change the class of the button to active. I use coffescript to set a value to the hidden field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the hidden field with CoffeeScript in your DOM, then you can very well add the class via CoffeeScript too by:

```
if $("#my_hidden_element").val() == 0
  $("#target").addClass 'active'
```

Interpreting the value of hidden field inside HAML will probably require you to embed script (which nobody usually wants) :)

Good luck